# R - how to make long rows by matching an element of original rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, test, defined like this:

```
id <- c(100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102)
v1 <- c(1,2,0,0,3,0)
v2 <- c(2,3,5,8,4,1)
test <- data.frame (id, v1, v2)
```

How can I make a new data frame, test2, where I have only three rows, matched by id.  Each row would have the following columns: id, v1.1, v2.1, v3.1, v1.2, v2.2, v3.2.  In other words, for each unique id, I would create a new row that combines the old rows that share this id. I would like to know how to do this.

Also, the above method is intended to figure out which id's have 0's for both observations.  I want to delete these.  For example, I would delete the two observations with id 101 because they both have 0's.  I would keep the two observations with id 102 because only one of them is a 0.  Is there another way to do this without doing the above method?

Thanks so much and Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: what if you have for the same id , one 0 for v1 and another 0  in v2 ,  do you will delete this row, or you will keep it?

Comment: I would keep that one.  What I can do now, after your very nice answer, is to create a new variable, call it sum, and define sum as v1.1 + v1.2.  Then check whether sum == 0.  If so, delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you tried to reshape data.frame in the wide format.

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~id,test,FUN=I)
   id v1.1 v1.2 v2.1 v2.2
1 100    1    2    2    3
2 101    0    0    5    8
3 102    3    0    4    1
```

Comment: When I try this solution with strings, Instead of keeping the none matching columns (id) in seperate columns, it combines them in a weird way: c("ABC", "CDE"). I am looking for a way where a funciton is not applied to the remaining columns, the table is just made wider.