# How to make longer based on ID column, *without* collapsing the remaining columns? - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, tidyr

Based on this question and answer, that is close to satisfying my needs: [R - how to make long rows by matching an element of original rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272507/r-how-to-make-long-rows-by-matching-an-element-of-original-rows)

```
df <- data.table::data.table(ID = c(123,123,123,234,456, 234),
             event_type = c("Museum","Concert","Park","Garden","Museum", "Museum"),
             event_info = c("5496:C", "5434:D", "1236:C", "534126:A", "5496:C", "0129:Z"))
```

and the output I want is:

```
ID event_type.1 event_type.2 event_type.3 event_info.1 event_info.2 event_info.3 
123      Museum      Concert         Park       5496:C       5434:D       1236:C 
234      Garden       Museum           NA     534126:A       0129:Z           NA
456      Garden           NA           NA       5496:C           NA           NA
```

In my real data, the min number of times an ID appears is 2x and the maximum is 4x.

per the solution linked, I tried `aggregate` but also tried a couple of `group_by` approaches but the issue is that I dont want to combine any columns or make new columns. I want to be able to see, for each `ID`, what are the pairs (or more than pair) of `event_type` while retaining the `event_info` for each of the `event_type`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I add a variable `instance` to track how many times we have encountered a given `ID` so far. Then I pivot wider using `instance` and the two value columns. By default, the new column names will first show the value columns (i.e. `event_type` or `event_info`) and then `_` and the `instance` number.

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(instance = row_number(), .by = ID) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = instance, values_from = c(event_type, event_info))
  # add names_sep = "." to get the column name formatting in the OP
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 7
     ID event_type_1 event_type_2 event_type_3 event_info_1 event_info_2 event_info_3
  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1   123 Museum       Concert      Park         5496:C       5434:D       1236:C      
2   234 Garden       Museum       NA           534126:A     0129:Z       NA          
3   456 Museum       NA           NA           5496:C       NA           NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you share a quick logic on the code? Maybe, how did you get think of the way to make ```pivot_wider work``` for this data?